# I want to extract strings from data

Tags: android

I have data with repeating pattern '@@@'.I want to extract all strings between this pattern.
The data is like -

```
son@@@can@@@e@@@nick@@@54@@@
```

how can i get all data between the pattern '@@@'.

Comment: i want to extract son,can,e,nick,54

Comment: `String[] arr= str.split(patternText);`?

Comment: this can be done using regex pattern matching but i m not so familier with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
String patternString = "@@@";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
String[] split = pattern.split(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner` with `"@@@"` delimiter.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner("son@@@can@@@e@@@nick@@@54@@@");

in.useDelimiter("@@@");

while(in.hasNext)
    String x = in.next();
    //Do something with x;
```

`x` will hold everything between `@@@`. You can easily store them in an `Array` inside the loop or use them anyway you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "son@@@can@@@e@@@nick@@@54@@@";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("[@]+", "");
```

or you can separate all world via

```
String rem = "@@@";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rem);
String[] splitarr = pattern.split(text);

for(int i=0;i<aplitarr.length();i++)
{
      String word=aplitarr[i].ToString();
}
```

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("@@@");
separated[0]; // this will contain "son"
separated[1]; // this will contain "can"
```

or

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, "@@@");
String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "son"
String second = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "can"
```